# Is there a better way to add subviews to UITableViewCell's?

Tags: ios

I'm adding a `UIImageView` subview but I'm currently creating that programatically. I feel bad about this. Is there an easier way to do this through the weird 'Prototype Cell' in my `UITableView`?

Ideally I could drop a `UIImageView` in the prototype cell within my storyboard then change its' value, but when I do that the cell is just empty. I'm not allowed to created outlets, either, of course.

Comment: Did you create and set a subclass so you can add the outlets to it?

Comment: No. Why would I subclass? I'm not allowed to make outlets from prototype cells.

Comment: Why would you feel bad creating a subview through code? You'd commit suicide from depression then if you saw my apps. They are ALL code.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily bother me to add subviews programmatically. I feel like it's easier and faster to change them through IB.

Answer (score 0):

The cell prototype needs to include a `UIImageView`. If you're using a storyboard select the cell prototype and make sure its style is set to `Basic` in the attributes inspector (right panel).

The cell identifier doesn't match the identifier typed in for your prototype cell in your storyboard. Make sure that `cell` is entered for `Identifier` also in the attributes inspector.

To check to see the image is in there,

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
    {
        let cellIdentifier = "cell"

        var cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) as UITableViewCell

        cell.textLabel.text = self.products[indexPath.row]
        var image : UIImage = UIImage(named: "myImage")
        cell.imageView.image = image

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your prototype cell to custom in the storyboard. Give your prototype cell an identifier value which will be dequeued later in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method. Drop the views you want within that prototype cell. For each subview you've dropped in the cell add a unique tag value in the storyboard. Make sure each subview has a unique tag number.

Implement all of the `UITableViewDelegate` methods as you normally do. In the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` delegate method you can get the image view instance as follows before returning cell:

`imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1)`

You aren't allowed to create outlets for repeating views, so you can't create outlets within prototype cells.

Comment: This is returning `nil`. Fice. I'm getting `nil` four times when I call `cell.viewWithTag(1)` Any idea why? I know the tag was applied.

Comment: @Arcrammer did you dequeued the cell properly with the same identifier which you have given in storyboard ? I can help you out if you can provide the github link of your project or at least update your question with the cellForRowAtIndexPath implementation of yours

Comment: I do have this project up at GitHub. I've since decided to create the subviews programmatically, but I still want to know how to do this so I've commented out my progress and reverted back to the point where I was trying to change the image subview. It's right over here: http://github.com/Arcrammer/Pictunes-iOS

Comment: @Arcrammer I think in Swift we need to use cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1) instead of cell.viewWithTag(1)
you presently using self.feedView.viewWithTag(1) which is completely wrong. Your are asking tableview for a view with tag which is inside content view of the cell
the actual order will be like this
tableview -> cell -> content view -> your views

Comment: Okay. That makes perfect sense, but now I've changed it to `cell.contentView.viewWithTag(1)` and I still have the same result. No image in my table view. Ideas?